# how to make a dynamic four column layout in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to fetch data (title , number and date) and put them into a box (green boxes) and put the boxes in one line in my website like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PQTI.png)

Each line can have 4 items but because the number of boxes are dynamic I can have only two box in one line.

***I want  to have an even space between the boxes even when there are only 2 boxes*** .I can't use
{ justify-content:space-between } because in this case I have two boxes, one **sticks at the right** side of the page and the other **sticks at the left** side
and I cant use {margin-right} or {margin-left} because in case I have 4 boxes **I want the boxes stick at the sides** like when I use
{ justify-content:space-between }

I will be happy if you help me with this issue

PS: I code in reactjs

Comment: `justify-content: space-evenly` isn't enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display: grid` to achieve what you have in the screenshot.  This comes with the added bonus of being able to set the size of the columns relative to each other:

```css
.boxcontainer{
  display: grid;                          /* Use grid type layout to get columns */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* Proportions of the columns */
  gap: 20px;                              /* Use gap here instead of margin in .box */
}
.box{
  width: 100%;    /* Use 100% of each column */
  height: 200px;  /* This can be whatever you want */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxcontainer">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `display:flex;` and `flex-wrap:wrap;` for the Container and add `padding` to it, you can achieve your goal:

```css
.container{
  width:1000px;
  display:flex;
  padding:10px;
}
.box{
  width:200px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```